# Why does hostname --fqdn only return the domain name?

Tags: debian, hostname

Relevant files (slightly anonymized):

```
heinzi@d2:~$ cat /etc/hostname
d2
heinzi@d2:~$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
<myexternalip>  d2.<myname>.at    <myname>.<myprovider>.at       <myname>

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

This output is correct:

```
heinzi@d2:~$ hostname
d2
heinzi@d2:~$ hostname --all-fqdns
d2.<myname>.at
```

But this I don't understand:

```
heinzi@d2:~$ hostname --fqdn
<myprovider>.at
```

Shouldn't it be `d2.<myname>.at`, since that's the first entry after `<myexternalip>`? And if it's the second entry, shouldn't it by `<myname>.<myprovider>.at` instead of just the domain name?

I'm aware that I could probably fix this by playing around with the hosts file, but I'd really like to *understand* why this happens. I read the hostname man page and googled and think that it *should* return `d2.<myname>.at` in my case. Thus, I'd really prefer an answer along the lines of "*This is because ...*" instead of "*Try ... and see if it works.*".

The system is Debian 7.5 "wheezy".

Comment: Instead of using <my name> use the words 'foo' and 'bar', it is easier to read.

Comment: @spuder: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind for my next question.

Comment: @spuder I see your point, but here, the term `Name` or `Provider` in the names are useful. Hmm... maybe you meant replacing `<myname>` not by `foo`, but by `fooName`? That's much better indeed.

Answer (score 3):

As it turns out, the culprit was `/etc/resolv.conf`. Changing:

```
search <myprovider>.at
nameserver ...
nameserver ...
nameserver ...
```

to

```
search <myname>.at <myprovider>.at
nameserver ...
nameserver ...
nameserver ...
```

fixes the issue.

(I'll leave the question open for the time being, just in case someone can come up with an explanation for this.)